# Как отредактировать мой код, чтобы звук сгенерированного текста передавался сразу в динамики, а не записывался в файл

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import io
import os
import torch
import torchaudio
from pydub.playback import play
from pydub import AudioSegment

def silero_voice(example_text):
    device = torch.device('cpu')
    torch.set_num_threads(4)
    local_file = 'model.pt'

    model = torch.package.PackageImporter(local_file).load_pickle("tts_models", "model")
    model.to(device)

    sample_rate = 48000
    speaker = 'aidar'

    audio_paths = model.save_wav(text=example_text, speaker=speaker, sample_rate=sample_rate)
    audio_file = AudioSegment.from_wav(audio_paths)
    play(audio_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, как там torchaudio, ибо у меня его нет(хотя torch установлен и работает), а вот простым playsound вполне играет

```
import playsound
.....
playsound.playsound("test.wav", block=True)
```